# Remove Localhost url in Blob

Tags: javascript, canvas, blob

Hi am new to canvas!!!

```
var blob = new Blob([uint8Array], { type: "image/png" });
$rootScope.blobVal = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

I used above code for  converting Canvas DataUrl to Blob Object from above snippet am getting **blobval** as URL like

> blob:http%3A//xyz.xyz.x.yz%3A8100/
>   4fa503b3-2e1d-4d38-b112-1f417c670b93

but i need only

> 4fa503b3-2e1d-4d38-b112-1f417c670b93

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: every browser I have tried this sort of code on includes the host in the blob url ... except IE/Edge ... so, what's the big deal if the host name is there? use IE if it bothers you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var blob = new Blob([uint8Array], { type: "image/png" });
var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
str_arr = objectUrl.split("/");
$rootScope.blobVal = str_arr[str_arr.length - 1];
```

$rootScope.blobVal contains 4fa503b3-2e1d-4d38-b112-1f417c670b93

Comment: that space wont be there in any browser I've tried.

Comment: in that case, split at / and pick the last item in the array :-)

Comment: even so, it wont be a valid blob url - you can't pick and choose how the internals of your browsers javascript engine works - you use the results as they stand, or recompile the browser

Comment: i need  **blobVal** as UID format instaead of it. just like **4fa503b3-2e1d-4d38-b112-1f417c670b93**

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks I agree with You but am asking about is there any way for getting like only UID format URLs